# Lenovo G580 Brightness Error caused by unsupported updates. How to revert?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, brightness, lenovo

I just installed the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 on my newly bought Lenovo G580.

The brightness control was working properly using the Live CD and when I first started the installed version.

Then I updated Ubuntu and restarted my laptop, and suddenly now, I can't change the brightness.

I think its caused by some update. And then I went and checked my update settings, and saw that Unsupported Updates (precise-backports) were enabled by default. So now I need to fix this brightness issue somehow.

What should I do to locate the wrong update and remove it?

I don't even mind removing all the updates right now.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: By unsupported updates you mean precise-backports or precise-proposed?

Comment: precise-backports

Comment: Updated the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the method to make brightness work.

I followed this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?s=87102a2aa7f21edc9a672787d430af4d&t=1875126&page=2

and I added `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` line, in `/etc/default/grub`

Then I ran: `sudo update-grub`

and I restarted my laptop, and it srtarted working. :D

Comment: Just to complete, the full line would become:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"